# How to implement a machine learning model in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic, knn

I have designed a machine learning model with the KNN algorithm that I want to integrate into anylogic, I can't do it. Someone can help me

Comment: The easiest way is probably just output data from AnyLogic model to external file and run your KNN on it. Unless you want to use output of KNN in simulation there is no need for direct integration. The question needs more detail and an example to help find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Python for KNN, you can use AnyLogic Pypeline to connect it to your simulation model. Please check here the instructions: https://www.anylogic.com/resources/educational-videos/webinar-pypeline-a-python-connector-library-for-anylogic/